# C# Web project can't use ISS express

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express

I want try to implementing this [source](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx), but it seems like my version of visual studio cant detect IIS express i installed from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264).

I use visual studio 2013 and windows 7 32bit.
here is the picture.[image]

Comment: That looks like a C++ project, not a C# project...

Comment: Exactly. Please check also if your IIS is properly installed: Start -> Run -> inetmgr. Click OK and you should see IIS configuration screen.

Comment: windows cannot find inetmgr, make sure you have typed the name correctly

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a 64-bit IIS Express on a 32-bit Windows 7 installation. Are you sure you have successfully installed 32-bit IIS Express?

Make sure you have downloaded iisexpress_x86_en-US.msi from the link you provided.

Comment: i have download and install 32bit version,.
i wont accidentally install 64bit, because it will gives me error